# configuring e-tags

Tags: optimization

I am using Yslow as a simple speed benchmarking tool and I came across a really confusing concept. The E-tag

So the main problem is : How do I configure E-tags? my grade in yslow says:

There are 19 components with misconfigured ETags

```
* http://thehotelinventory.com/media/js/jquery.min.js
* http://thehotelinventory.com/media/js/jquery.colorbox.min.js
* http://thehotelinventory.com/media/js/easyslider.min.js
* http://thehotelinventory.com/media/js/jquery.tools.min.js
* http://thehotelinventory.com/media/js/custom.min.js
* http://thehotelinventory.com/media/js/jquery.validate.min.js
* http://thehotelinventory.com/media/images/colorbox/loading_background.png
* http://thehotelinventory.com/media/images/productheaderbg.jpg
* http://thehotelinventory.com/media/images/buttons/field-bg. //etc
```

I browsed through the developer.yahoo.com guidelines on website optimization yet I can't really understand the thing with e-tags

Comment: You will likely get a better answer if you post what you are able to change, such as whether you can admin your server and what OS it is as well as what if any programming languages you are using for the site. Without that information nobody will be able to tell you how to change the settings and you will just get general information.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[This page](http://www.bytestopshere.com/post.cfm/disable-remove-etags-on-iis-6-to-improve-performance) shows how to disable ETags for IIS and [this page](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/apache-speed-etags/) shows how to do it for Apache.

Comment: For Apache I had to first turn on mod_headers, and did this by running the following command `a2enmod headers`

Comment: Correct, the Header directive is part of the mod_headers Module so that module would need to be enabled first. http://www.askapache.info//2.3/mod/mod_headers.html#header

Comment: For those on Apache, AskApache.com has changed their site structure without adding any redirects. The new URL is: http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/apache-speed-etags/

Comment: Awesome, thanks Michael, I updated the link in my answer.

Comment: A minimal answer should be included in the actual post. Links can break.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you are running Apache...

You can set up a simple ETag like this:

```
FileETag MTime Size
```

If you have multiple servers, you want to disable ETags.

```
FileETag None
```

Put the above code in your `httpd.conf` (if you have access), otherwise you can put it in `.htaccess`.

Comment: Putting "FileETag MTime Size" in .htaccess did not help in my case. But putting it in httpd.conf and restarting Apache did work however. Here is a more detailed example: https://studio.tellme.com/vxml2/ovw/perf/cache_apache13.html#inode_etags

Comment: httpd.conf is a better solution, but .htaccess should work fine if you have AllowOverride on.

Comment: Why do you wnat disable ETags if you have multiple servers ? If you specify the first configuration you mention for ETags then the inode number will not be taken in consideration for ETag generation so it will be safe even for multiple servers.

Answer (score 7):

Think of E-Tags as a sort of hash.  When a browser makes a request for a resource, it sends along the E-tag of the file version it has cached.  If the server decides that the files are similar enough (there are "strong" and "weak" versions of E-Tags so it's not always a simple comparison check) it will send a "304 Not Modified" response to the client, rather than the resource itself.  This translates into a speed boost, since it prevents bandwidth from being wasted on unchanged files.

E-Tags are sent via HTTP headers.

There's a good example of E-Tags at work (and also how to disable them for Apache) here:
http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/apache-speed-etags.html

Comment: AskApache.com has changed their site structure without adding any redirects. The new URL is: http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/apache-speed-etags/

Answer (score 6):

By removing the ETag header, you disable caches and browsers from being able to validate files, so they are forced to rely on your Cache-Control and Expires header.

Add these lines to `.htaccess`:

```
<ifModule mod_headers.c>   
Header unset ETag
</ifModule>
FileETag None
```

Answer (score 3):

Go straight to the source, YSlow provides guidance on all of it's advice, including how to [configure ETags](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags).

Answer (score 1):

The best way to configure your ETags is to remove them.  For static files, far-future expiration dates are a much better approach.

The way to remove them depends on the web server you're using. For IIS 7, it can be done with a simple HttpModule.

Comment: Why is a far-future expiration date a better approach? In what context?

Answer (score 0):

Entity tags are a feature of the HTTP protocol, see http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt

> Entity tags are used for comparing two or more entities from the same
>      requested resource. HTTP/1.1 uses entity tags in the ETag (section
>      14.19), If-Match (section 14.24), If-None-Match (section 14.26), and
>      If-Range (section 14.27) header fields. The definition of how they
>      are used and compared as cache validators is in section 13.3.3. An
>      entity tag consists of an opaque quoted string, possibly prefixed by
>      a weakness indicator.

Answer (score 0):

wikipedia is the man's best friend:)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag

Basically a hash as ShZ said, that should be unique or almost for a file.